# How to detect holes within a contour using python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I use AI training to generate image masks for analyzing specific elements of images. In this particular problem, I am wanting to use cv2 to moderate the "health" of those image masks. For example, I have a mask that has 1 single rectangle shape that is filled. Our AI model creates multiple .bmp's of this filled rectangle and colors it red. So I have a red contour that is just a solid rectangle. How can I check 1. the rectangularity of the contour, and 2. that there are no holes within the rectangle (meaning the contour is entirely filled)?

I initially was going to check the rectangle's area and assume if it was "large enough" then I could assume there were no holes. But this code model will be used on rectangles of various sizes, so using the area to check for holes will not suffice, unless I found the width*length and used that as my area variable, but I was curious if there is an easier way to do this. As for the rectangularity, I am entirely unsure of how to do that or where to even start. if someone could even point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Use contour hierarchy to check for child contours inside the parent contour.

Comment: If you need more help, please add sample images and the code you have tried. [ask]